# Correct def for expression

Tags: clojure

I have this function:

```
(defn get-validator []
  (UrlValidator. (into-array ["https"])))
```

I want it to be evaluated only once, on the first call, then just return the result. Which is the better way to write it:

```
(def get-validator (UrlValidator. (into-array ["https"])))

(def ^:const get-validator (UrlValidator. (into-array ["https"])))

(defonce get-validator (UrlValidator. (into-array ["https"])))
```

Or is there another way that is better? Documentation suggests that `defonce` is the correct one, but it's not clearly stated.

Comment: `defonce` is exactly what you're looking for. I don't know why any other option would be considered suitable.

Comment: Although in this case it doesn't produce a function and it computes the value not on the first use but on the ns require. If the "on the first" use requirement is important, you can use e.g. `delay` outside of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `def` sets a var with the given name and optionally the
given "init" value in that var, when the namespace is loaded/compiled
(note that there is basically not much of a difference between loading
and compiling and that's the reason, why you don't want to have
side-effects in your `def`).

Roughly all three versions are the same, with the following differences:

- `:^const` allows inlining this value; so this effects the following
  forms, when they are compiled and might improve performance in the
  following code
- `defonce` prevents re-def-ining the var again once the namespace is
  *reloaded*; this is most useful if you `def` mutable state, that you
  want to survive over reloading your code

In any case, requiring the ns for the first time, will execute the code
to init the var.  Then it is basically left alone (imagine a static
property in a Java class with a static initializer).

All that said: if `UrlValidator` has internal state you might still be
better off using a function to create a fresh one, whenever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, assuming `UrlValidator.` is referentially transparent, is to use `clojure.core/memoize`.

So

```clj
(defn get-validator []
  (UrlValidator. (into-array ["https"])))
(def uval (memoize get-validator))
```

And then use `(uval)` whenever you need the validator.  Because of the memoization, `get-validator` will be called only once.

This approach will make only one call to `UrlValidator.` the first time `(uval)` is executed.  All the other suggestions will call `UrlValidator.`, once, when the namespace is loaded.